# Python handling errors after handling an error inside try-except block

Tags: python, error-handling, try-except

```
try:
    print(1)
    assert 2 + 2 == 5
except AssertionError:
    print(3)
except:
    print(4)
```

In this code after handling that assertion error by `except AssertionError:` the `except: print(4)` doesn't work.

But if I create an error after the AssertionError like this:

```
try:
    print(1)
    assert 2 + 2 == 5
except AssertionError:
    print(3)
    print(2/0)
except:
    print(4)
```

it gives an error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#14>", line 3, in <module>
    assert 2 + 2 == 5
AssertionError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#14>", line 6, in <module>
    print(2/0)
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

But why? It suppose to except that error too. Because that error happen inside the try except block.

Comment: The error doesn't happen inside the `try` block. Code inside the exception block is just code. It itself isn't protected from errors.

Answer (score 0):

In a `try - except` block, the only errors filtered are those that occurred under the `try` statement. For example, if you want to trigger the last `except` instead of the `AssertionError` then you can try:

```py
try:
    print(1)
    raise(IOError) #To trigger the last except
    assert 2 + 2 == 5
except AssertionError:
    print(3)
except:
    print(4)
```

which should output:

```py
1
4
```

Remember that any errors not under a `try` statement directly cannot be filtered by the `except`.

Answer (score 0):

As the [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59960649/12802280) correctly describes, the `ZeroDivisionError` does not occur inside the `try` block. If you need to catch that exception, from within the first `except` block, then you'll need to do something like:

```
try:
    print(1)
    assert 2 + 2 == 5
except AssertionError:
    try:
        print(3)
        print(2/0)
    except:
        print(4) # this except block will execute during print(2/0)
except:
    pass #this except block will never execute
```